# Error performing TLS handshake: Could not negotiate a supported cipher suite

Tags: networking

When connecting to my library's WiFi, the following "Hotspot Login" window opens with a TLS handshake error (title):

[image: Hotspot Login]

If I copy the URL located near the lock icon in the image (blurred out here) into my browser, the expected library WiFi login page appears and I can access the internet swimingly.

Firstly, am I losing any of the HTTPS security benefits by doing this? And secondly, how can this be fixed? I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using Chrome.